# module 'cvzone' has no attributed 'Classifier'

Tags: python, cvzone

Trying to make a program identifying sign language but encountered this problem. Im expecting it to use my webcam to see which ASL sign I am showing on the webcam.

[image: screenshot of the error I'm getting]

Answer (score 0):

They moved `Classifier` into the  `ClassificationModule` in `1.5.4` version of cvzone. Now, the way to do it would be to import-

`from cvzone.ClassificationModule import Classifier`

and then

`myClassifier = Classifier('MyModel/keras_model.h5','MyModel/labels.txt')`